# The elements of my page are not sized/aligned as I want them to be

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

The fiddle for my code is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/wasingej/k2GPw/

I think the problem has something to do with how I specify right/left aligned divs but I'm not sure:

```
div.right
{
    float:right;
    margin-right: 2%;
    border-style:solid;
}
```

As you can see, the fiddle produces a jumbled mess of garbage.  My goal was to have the page look similar to this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1tk5.png

I'm fairly new to css so I'm guessing that my problem is caused by something fairly obvious.  Any ideas?

Comment: At the risk of summoning the markup pedants, you could make really good use of a table here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey.. Oh lord...

Comment: Agree with @RobertHarvey this looks like tabular data.

Comment: I have heard and read that tables should not be used to organize content.  Is this case an exception to what seems to be a consensus among web developers?

Comment: Even the pedants agree that using a table for tabular data is perfectly fine.  That's what it's for, after all.

Comment: Checkout this article re: when to use tables: http://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/

Answer (score 2):

Okay here's a very simple example of doing this with a table. This data appears to be tabular in nature, so while there are wonks who insist a table is NEVER okay, using a table for tabular data is appropriate.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan=2>List 1 Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Owner 1 Name:</td>
            <td>Owner 1 Status</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Owner 2 Name:</td>
            <td>Owner 2 Status</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Owner 3 Name:</td>
            <td>Owner 3 Status</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 2%;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 1% 2%;
}
td:first-child {
    text-align: right;
}
thead th {
    text-align: center;
}
```

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BUp82/

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this, is that if you re-size the browser all of the contents get squished together.  
Other than that this works.

Comment: @Jonco98 Ah well simply change the table CSS width to a fixed em or pixel width instead of a percentage (same on padding).

Answer (score 0):

Your issues are stemming from two things... proper handling of floats and overflows
This forked fiddle should show you your expected results: **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/2MkQJ/)**

The main bit of css that you need to add is this:

```
div.outer
{
//... your existing css ...
overflow: hidden;
}
```

I also added a 100% wide DIV around the title areas like this:

```
div.title { width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-align: center; }
```

*my fiddle has min-height and min-width set for demonstration purposes